# Backward elimination in multiple polynomial regression?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, polynomial

I'm working on multiple regression models (with R), and the use of polynomials can increase my adj r-squared. However, I'm a bit confused because if I add polynomials, the adj r-squared decreases, but if I delete the basic value and keep the squared one, the adj r is still high, and the p-values are all < 0.05.

**My question is**: can I do the backward elimination and delete the basic value, keeping the squared one?

These are my data:
age - age^2 - age^3 - height - height^2 - height^3 - HR/age - HR/age^2 - HR/age^3

So can I do forward or backward elimination?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This seems like a variant of stepwise regression, [which is fraught with problems](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/).

Comment: Well, I'm not doing a stepwise actually..

Comment: Can you share the function call so that it is clear which parameters you are using?

Comment: What is your actual regression equation?   Have you tried plotting your target variable against age, height, and HR/age to see if / how nonlinear the relationships are?

Comment: My actual regression equation is: Y = b0 + m1sex + m2age + m3height +  m4HR which produces an adj-r of 0.60. Following another study, they did the quadratic and cubic reg of these parameters and also the divisions (HR/age etc..). 
I would do the same since their last model was built with quadratic and "division" items.